# How to display relative file path in cout statement

Tags: c++, file, path, cout

I'm trying to display the relative file path to my program file in a cout statement so it appears on the screen. This is what I have written down, but the computer mistakes the backslash as an exit sequence. It presents the following error:

> Fross12.cpp:62:12: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\C'

This is the code I have written that I'm working with:

```
cout << "C:\COSC-1303\Assignment-12> Fross12.exe < big-coin-file.txt" << endl;
```

What I want is to have the computer display the following:

> C:\COSC-1303\Assignment-12> Fross12.exe < big-coin-file.txt

Comment: You need to escape back slashes by using 2 of them or use a raw string literal: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ (and most other C-based langauges), \ is used to indicate an escape character (e.g. \r, \n, \t, etc). If you want to have an actual "\" character in your string, you must escape it: \.

In your case, code should be modified as:
     `cout << "C:\\COSC-1303\\Assignment-12> Fross12.exe < big-coin-file.txt" << endl;`

From C++11, we can also use raw string to treat a string as it is without processing escape charcters.
To create a raw string, use syntax: R"(your_string_value)".

E.g:
`cout << R"(C:\COSC-1303\Assignment-12> Fross12.exe < big-coin-file.txt)" << endl;`

Comment: Last sentence is wrong.  Once it is in a string it is too late, the escape processing has already been done and eaten the backslashes.  Doubled backslashes are only a thing in source code, not in runtime string data.

Comment: Nice catch Ben. I totally missed it. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `\\` to escape the backslash character so it's not interpreted special, *or* just use forward slashes `/` - That works on both Windows, Unix and other Operating Systems.

You can also use a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) like `R"my_raw_str(C:\whatever)my_raw_str"`.

You could also use a [std::filesystem::path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) which takes care of all the details for you.